# Copy a file and paste it to the desired location

Tags: android

I want to copy a file from say /mnt/sdcard/Pictures and paste to the location /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/myselection..
how to code it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Java I/O](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CopyFile.html). Do not hardcode `/mnt/sdcard` as a path, as that is invalid on some Android devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.